# How to make this asynchronous call, synchronous

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have an associative array date as key, the value in this case is an array of objects. Now in this object

```
while (tempDate < endDate) {
    $scope.dates.push(tempDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
    var dailyTrips = response.data[tempDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY")];
    for (var i = 0; i < dailyTrips.length; i++) {
        // console.log(moment(dailyTrips[i].trip.startTime).format("hh:mm a"));
        // console.log(moment(dailyTrips[i].trip.endTime).format("hh:mm a"));
        geocode(dailyTrips, i);      
    }
    tempDate.add(1, 'days');
}
$scope.data = response.data;

var geocode = function(dailyTrips, i) {
    (function() {
        var latlng = {
             lat: dailyTrips[i].trip.source.latitude,
             lng: dailyTrips[i].trip.source.longitude
        };
        console.log(latlng);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        geocoder.geocode({
            'location': latlng
        }, function(result, status) {
            if (result[1]) {
                console.log(result[1].address_components[0].long_name+" "+result[1].address_components[2].long_name);
            }
        });
    }(i));
};
```

Now This code is working but running at completely different times as it's a callback. I wanted to have this all at one time so that I can use it in ng-repeat and show everything nicely. How do I do that? 
Expected output

```
Trip StartTime    Trip from 
Trip EndLine      Trip To
```

**EDIT 1: Still not working**

```
 while (tempDate < endDate) {
     $scope.dates.push(tempDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
     var dailyTrips = response.data[tempDate.format("DD-MM-YYYY")];
     var promises = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < dailyTrips.length; i++) {
         promises[i] = geocode(dailyTrips, i);
     }
     $q.all(promises).then(function(result) {
         console.log(result); //line 39
     });
     tempDate.add(1, 'days');
 }
 $scope.data = response.data;

        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error.data);
        });

    var geocode = function(dailyTrips, i) {
    var q = $q.defer();
    var latlng = {
        lat: dailyTrips[i].trip.source.latitude,
        lng: dailyTrips[i].trip.source.longitude
    };
    console.log(latlng);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'location': latlng
    }, function(result, status) {
        console.log(status);
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(result[1].address_components[0].long_name + " " + result[1].address_components[2].long_name);
            q.resolve(result[1].address_components[0].long_name + " " + result[1].address_components[2].long_name);
        } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                geocode(dailyTrips, i);
            }, 500);
        } else {
            q.reject();
        }
    });
    return q.promise;
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make an async call synchronous, except by blocking your code, which you do no NOT want to do. Instead, I suggest you convert geocode into a promise

```
var geocode = function(dailyTrips, i) {
    return this.$q((resolve, reject) => {
       ....
```

and then wait for all the promises to complete

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < dailyTrips.length; i++) {
   promises[i] = geocode(dailyTrips, i);      
}
$q.all(promises).then( function(results) {...} );
```

Comment: I have edited the question. It is still not working... could you possibly point out the flaw? The issue is that the outermost quickly evaluates all the promises and does not wait for the promises to resolve... How do I battle that issue

Comment: I suggest you remove the IFFE, and you need to put `$scope.data = response.data;` in the `.then` callback

Comment: You might get a clearer picture seeing the recent edits and I also have commented the line number in my code. It still doesn't work.. :(